# Memory management scope in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection, malloc, free

When freeing memory in C and C++, do I only need the memory address or does it require any specific variable?

So if I were to do something such as:

```
int* test()
{
    int* x = new int(5);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* y = test();

    delete y;

    return 0;
}
```

Would this cause memory leaks? Thanks!

Comment: No leaks here. However avoid such code where memory is allocated via a function and deallocd manually. Another developer using the function test without this knowledge is the reason for quite a lot of memory leak issues..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there wouldn't be any leaks there, but then again, neither would there be in

```
int test()
{
    return 5;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int y = test();
    return 0;
}
```

Avoid dynamic allocation if you can.

Comment: *Avoid dynamic allocation if you can.* True. And if you can't avoid it, use smart pointers.

Comment: Oh no no, silly. I wouldn't actually that willingly throw dynamic allocation around. It was just an example that dictated what I was trying to explain in my question. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as it is, does not leak (as others have already said). However, it requires **very little** to break and potentially leak:

```
int* test()
{
    int* x = new int(5);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* y = test();
    int* z = test();
    delete y;
    delete z;
    return 0;
}
```

This code now potentially leaks because `new` can throw, and if the second call to `new` (`z=...`) throws then the first pointer (`y`) can never be deleted. Any other function that can throw (not just a second call to `new`) will pose the same problem.

---

This is why smart pointers are a must-have: they use RAII and allow you to write exception-safe code, which is the basis of decent C++. This code simply cannot leak:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> test()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int(5));
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> y = test();
    std::unique_ptr<int> z = test();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `pointer` is, as ist name states, just an address pointing to an object on the heap. So what you do works perfectly fine.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426616/c-programming-return-pointer-to-freed) for a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the memory address to free the allocated space. But make sure you free it accordingly (in C++), i.e., call `delete y[]` if it was an array, like that...

In C, you just need the base address only and when you call `free()`, the complete allocated space will be freed.
There won't be any memory leaks in your code.